# Securing webapp with UI & service Layer

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am developing a web app which will consist on two different deployments: one containing the service layer (services, database access, etc.) with a REST endpoint, and on the other hand a UI layer that only has a presentation layer based on the data retrieved by consuming the REST endpoint of the service layer.

I am using Spring to develop both apps, so the natural idea would be to secure the application using Spring Security.

But how would I go to achieve that? I guess the login page should be on the UI layer but how do I share security concerns through both apps? Is there any bibliography on a similar case?

Note that these two deployments do not necessarily reside in the same container.

Answer (score 0):

usually the REST service layer runs on a separate server with a notion of authentication, for example Basic or Digest authentication that spring security supports out of the box.

Clients of the REST service will either use a REST login service to authenticate themselves and make further requests by passing a session token alongside the request, or more frequently sign each request with a REST API key, that was pre-assigned to each client.

In this case the client of the REST service is the frontend server that serves the login page and any other pages of the web application, as well as replies to the pages ajax requests, that cannot go directly to the REST server due to the same origin policy.

This way there are two separate setups of spring security: Basic Authentication/Digest/custom authentication on the REST side, and form-login authentication on the frontend server side.

The user identifies itself to the frontend server, and the frontend server identifies itself to the REST server. The data served to a page might be a combination of several REST calls.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer. Just one more question: what if my authentication is through a database of users? My data access mechanisms are in the REST layer, but the authentication takes place in the UI layer.

Comment: The UI layer can do the authentication against the database table, the REST interface usually authenticates not the UI users but the program that is calling it (the frontend server) via it's API key

Comment: No it can't, as I said my ui layer is in a different environment and thus the only access it has to the data repository is through the REST api